# wamp Server Can't export Phpexcel file in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, wamp, phpexcel, wiki

This picture shows the error that occurs when using wamp server. But when using xampp, not any error display easily export excel file. How to fix this error on wamp server? [A CodeIgniter project]

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the class name and "extends" keyword is correct